# JWT Tokenization skip URL for Custom Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I want to skip the JWT Token authentication for the /preImages request.

I already tried this in JwtSecurityConfig File but it didn't work.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/preImages");
}
```

In my ServerApplication, I wrote this method to achieve it:

```
//JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;

public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter() {
    super("/api/**");
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

    String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorisation");


    if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Token ")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("JWT Token is missing");
    }

    String authenticationToken = header.substring(6);

    JwtAuthenticationToken token = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authenticationToken);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}


@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}

//JwtSecurityConfig.java

import java.util.Collections;

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(authenticationProvider));
}

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
    JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtSuccessHandler());
    return filter;
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests( ).antMatchers( "/api/preImages" ).permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.headers().cacheControl();

}

}
```

But for "/api/preImages" request also it says "JWT Token is missing".

JWT Tokenization skip URL for Custom Page

Answer (score 0):

To add paths you want to exclude from filtering/security you need to override one more method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/preImages");
}
```

Second approach might be do not throw an Exception in filter when no token found in header but create a "guest" Authentication.

Comment: i already tried it,It didn't work.

Comment: Did you remove .antMatchers( "/api/preImages" ).permitAll() ?

Comment: yes i removed still no change

Comment: hm, then try second approach - remove an exception and create "guest" Authentication for the case when no token provided.

Comment: How do i do that?